# I can't download intel haxm without admin

Tags: android-studio

Hey I want to install HAXM for android studio but the problem is that there is administration on my device.....is there any other way to install without that domain or I should use an external emulator?

Comment: HAXM can't be installed without administration privileges ...

Comment: is there any alrenatives??